# iLOM Boot device SUN X4170

Tags: boot, x86

I have configured the boot device to CD-ROM but whenever I reboot the server, it defaults to `boot_device=default`. Pressing F2/F8 during POST does not bring the BIOS setup.

```
set boot_device=cdrom Set 'boot_device' to 'cdrom'

-> show

/HOST Targets: diag

Properties:
    boot_device = cdrom
    generate_host_nmi = (Cannot show property)

Commands:
    cd
    set
    show
```

If I can get to OK prompt from iLOM, I can type `boot cdrom` - I just can't get the information on how to get to OK prompt in SUN X4170.

Comment: Is it possible your CD drive isn't connected properly? Can you disconnect your hard drives and then boot off of it?

Comment: There's no OS in HDD. Its a new server I'm trying to install OS.Am I doing it correctly?Why is iLOM reporting boot_device=default even after changing it to boot_device=cdrom?

Comment: The point of disconnecting any hard drives is to test if you can boot from CD at all. You may want to PXE boot or something, if not.

Comment: Removed HDD but i'm not even reaching HDD...Just goes to ILOM.

Comment: I'm look to your support docs, haven't worked with a Sun server in a really long time.